# Postifx + policyd blacklisted CC

Tags: postfix, policyd

I've configured a postfix with policyd to manage whitelist/blacklist. But my main problem is:

If one email is sended to a recipient and there are some CC o BCC that is blacklisted, all the email is "discarded" and it does not arrived to the main recipient, even if it is allowed.

So, it looks like if some recipient (RCPT to, cc o bcc) is blacklisted, postfix + policyd discard all the email. I think this should not be the normal behaviour, am I wrong?

Is there any configuration that allow that? or I am misunderstanding something.
here is a partial postfix conf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        reject_unauth_pipelining,
        reject_non_fqdn_sender,
        reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
        #policyd
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031,
        permit_mynetworks,
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject_unverified_recipient,
        check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10045,
        reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
        reject_rbl_client psbl.surriel.com,
        reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client xbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client combined.rbl.msrbl.net,
        reject_rbl_client relays.ordb.org,
        reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
        reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
        reject_rbl_client dnsbl.njabl.org,
        permit
```

If someone needs more information, do not hesitate to ask for it!

Answer (score 1):

It is the normal behavior.

- **Please do NOT use relays.ordb.org**. It is dead for five years.
- **Please do NOT use list.dsbl.org**. It is dead for three years.
- Don't use SBL, XBL and SBL-XBL if you already use ZEN! See http://www.spamhaus.org/zen/

Your Postfix setup is heavily broken!!!

And you do not know that recipients can't be "blacklisted". Only IPs or hostnames are blacklisted.

Comment: thanks for the info about rbl, I just copied from somewhere, but I have not used them because my server is not in production. I will solve that.

Comment: why a recipient domain can not be blacklisted? what about if I want that a user cant send to an specific domain or user?

Comment: @magiza83 senders can be blacklisted. Not recipients (-hostnames, -domains)